# Why '404 not found' doesn't works?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, http-status-code-404

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't apache show a 404 error when I send a 404 header with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247352/why-doesnt-apache-show-a-404-error-when-i-send-a-404-header-with-php)

The code is this:

```
<?PHP
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
exit;
?>
```

If I open the website in a browser, I will get a blank site, not a 404 error.
The headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2012 21:48:57 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

What did I wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1247352/212218

Comment: Your PHP script doesn't echo anything to the page, so of course you get a blank site. The headers do say `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`, which means that you set the 404 status correctly.

Comment: :'(  so it isn't possible with PHP?